# Django Query first ForeignKey of an object in a query

Tags: django

Trying to run a query on ordered store instances by distance, and then query the first Foreignkey Coupon of each store Instance. I am trying to show a coupon from each nearby store.

Location works fine via GeoDjango, my trouble is the query

**models.py**

```
...
class Store(models.Model):
   location = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True, blank=True)


class Coupon(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='coupon')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**views.py**

```
class homeView(View):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

       store_nearby = Store.objects.annotate(distance = Distance("location", user_location)).order_by("distance")

    context = {
        'store_list': store_nearby,
        # 'offer': offer,
    }
    return render(self.request, 'mysite/home_page.html', context)
```

**home_page.html**

```
{% for object in store_list %}
    {% for coupon in object.coupon.first %} // This doesnt work
        {{ coupon.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what is "offer" in template? Where it originates?

Comment: As I see there should be object.coupon.first

Comment: Its a mistake.I changed the models from my original code to different wording, so that it is easier to interpret (store, coupon), offer is equal to coupon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
{% for object in store_list %}
    {{ object.coupon.first.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

**OR**

Add the title as with queryset like this(using [**`subquery`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

...
coupons = Coupon.objects.filter(store=OuterRef('pk'))
store_nearby = Store.objects.annotate(distance = Distance("location", user_location)).annotate(coupon_title=Subquery(coupons.values('title')[:1])).order_by("distance")
```

And use it in template:

```
{% for object in store_list %}
    {{ object.coupon_title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Second solution is much optimum as it will reduce DB hits.

Comment: Top one worked. But I will try to get the second one to work to decrease the amount of queries. Thanks